# skewed background image animation

Tags: css, jquery-animate, skew

I'm currently working on http://mijnwebsitebestellen.be/index.php.
When you hover over 'event location' you can see the width of the first black & white band changes, however the background image is not skewed during the animation.

Here is a snippet of the code i use for the animation:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    $('.deel1-link').mouseover(function(){
        $('.deel1').animate({width:"600px"},400);
        $('.delen .col-sm-4:nth-child(1)').animate({width:"600px"},400);
       
    });
    
    $('.deel1-link').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.deel1').animate({width:"50px"},400);
        $('.delen .col-sm-4:nth-child(1)').animate({width:"50px"},400);
    });
});
```

I added a screenshot of the problem.[image]

Is there a fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you try css animation instead of jquery?

Comment: Does not work: 
.deel1-link:hover .deel1{ }
Because deel1-link is not a parent or a sibling ?

Comment: Look at this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/tmxjv0qb/ if you want onclick. If on hover only css https://jsfiddle.net/tmxjv0qb/2/

Comment: The problem is i can not make the link 'Event location' (= .deel1-link) is not a sibling or a parent or a sibling of the div with the skewed background image (= .deel1) .. If you inspect the code at http://mijnwebsitebestellen.be/ you'll understand. It's hard to explain.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand. Where's deel1-link?

Comment: This screenshot will clear things up: https://imgur.com/a/W7Vin